# Styling inside datable header, in LWC Component

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds, slds-styling-hooks

I have a datatable LWC element thatneeds to be responsive. So here it is in desktop

[image: table in wide screen]

an here in a cellphone screen size

[image]

HTML (just the datatable)

```
<lightning-combobox
   name="locationSelection"
   value={locationChoice}
   label="selection"
   placeholder="Select Location"
   options={options}
   onchange={handleLocationChange}
```

and the JS columns definition

```
const JOB_COLS = [
    {
        label: 'Job Name', 
        fieldName: 'link', 
        type: 'url', 
        typeAttributes: {
            label: { 
                fieldName: 'Name'
            }
        },
        cellAttributes: {
            class: 'slds-text-heading_medium headerStyle',
        }
    }, { 
        label: 'Oversized?',
        fieldName: 'oversized',   
        type: 'boolean', 
        cellAttributes: {
            iconName: { fieldName: 'oversized' }
        }
    }, { 
        label: 'Pickup Location',
        fieldName: 'location'
    }, { 
        label: 'Job Status',
        fieldName: 'status'
    }, { 
        label: 'Created Date',
        fieldName: 'createdDate',
        type: 'String'
    }, { 
        label: 'Web Name',
        fieldName: 'SuppliedName'
    }, { 
        label: 'Collection Point',
        fieldName: 'collectionPoint'
    }, 
];

const JOBSTATUS_OPTIONS = [
    { label: 'Available Jobs', value: 'available' },
    { label: 'Assigned Jobs', value: 'assigned' },
    { label: 'My Current jobs', value: 'myJobs' },
];
```

the issues id like to solve are only in mobile:

- the space between label and field information
- formatting labels

i tried with styling hooks, and given the field labels are table headers, i thought this Styling Hook would be it:

```
:host{
    --slds-c-th-text-padding: 15px;
}
```

but its ignored. And the only place regarding css, to put in the object for the columns, is in cellAttributes, that wont do affect the header of the column. If i could make the hook work, id put it here

```
@media (max-width: 767.98px) { 
    /* hook */
}
```

And i have seen solutions like: https://www.salesforcetroop.com/datatable_styling_in_lwc
that seem like hacking salesforce slds. Seems anti-pattern